# Outlook 2013 creating a black border line to the right of each nested table

Tags: html, html-table, border, html-email, outlook-2013

Please help, I'm at my wits end as I'm trying to make a responsive email, going from two columns to a single one, everything goes perfect until I reach Outlook2013, it adds a single black line to the right of each table that is aligned next to each other.
I've tried to reset it with the border-collapse:collapse function, but it's not having any effect.
I basically have two tables left aligned in a tablecell.

```
  <tr>
        <td align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse"><table width="300" border="0" style="border-collapse:collapse" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="contenttable" align="left">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="headercell" height="399" width="300" style="line-height:399px"><p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"><img src="image" style="display:block; width:100% height:auto" alt="" border="0px" height="399" width="300" /></p></td>
        </table> <table width="300" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="contenttable" style=" border-collapse:collapse" align="left">
          <tr>
            <td align="left" class="headercell"><p style="mso-table-lspace:0;mso-table-rspace:0;"><img src="image" style="display:block; width:100% height:auto" alt="" /></p></td>
        </table></td>
      </tr>
```

Comment: You chose the wrong icon in the editor that's all. (quote instead of code) I fixed that for you.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I find that the colour of the mystery border is the same as the `background-color` on the `body` element. EG if you have a green background with white content areas, the lines will be green on white.

To fix it in this case you can set the `body` background to be white and that will fix it. The gaps are still there, but you can't see them. You would then apply the green background colour to a container table instead.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah. That's Outlook showing the 1px gaps/borders it keeps between floated tables. You cannot get rid of it. Kinda. You can recolor it though.

For the little 1px gaps/lines you need to add:

```
border: 1px solid #COLOR;
```

to every floated table being sure to adjust the width of your tables to avoid "float drop". Where #COLOR is the background color of your tables.

If you're having problems with BIG gaps you need to put this in your head in a style tag:

```
table {mso-table-lspace:0pt;mso-table-rspace:0pt; border-collapse:collapse;}
```